# Trouble transitioning from paralist to enumitem

Tags: enumitem, paralist

I'm changing over from `paralist` to `enumitem` but encounter the following problem.  The code below does not compile, presumably because `enumitem` does not like an `equation` environment inside an `enumerate*` environment.  Any suggestions on how to fix this, other than reverting to `paralist?`  Yes, I do want to do this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}


\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=\emph{(\alph*)}]
\item Hello
\begin{equation}
 Uh=Oh
\end{equation}
\end{enumerate*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the mode `unboxed`:

```
\begin{enumerate*}[label=\emph{(\alph*)},mode=unboxed]
```

(Admittedly, setting the mode to `boxed` as the default value was not a good idea.)

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I could/should have found that in the manual, but didn't.

Comment: To be fair, the manual says very little about the implications of the `boxed` vs. the `unboxed` mode. The former has some (severe) limitations which I didn't explain at all.